# Ionic 3- How to check if event parameter exists?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

When I click a button to go to a page with segments, a page gets opened with a specific segment selected by an event that gets published.

```
this.event.subscribe('day', (res) => {
        console.info(res);
        this.days = res;
    });
```

This works fine, except for the first time I open the app. I also have tabs at the bottom and if you go to that ^^ same page but using the tabs, i get a blank page with nothing on it. I tried to log the variable out to see if it's undefined but i get nothing. How can I check if that variable is undefined or exists?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to log the variable out to see if it's undefined but i get nothing. How can I check if that variable is undefined or exists?

Use an [`== null` check](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/javascript/null-undefined.html) for `undefined` and `null` e.g.

```
this.event.subscribe('day', (res) => {
    if (res != null) {
      this.days = res;
    }
});
```

Comment: I keep doing that but I get nothing, no log no nothing.